# how to get log group name for a lambda in serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, serverless-framework

```
functions:
  logs:
    handler: src/handlers/logs.handler
```

How can I get the log group name for this function "logs".

Currently, I am forming a string.

> /aws/lambda/logs-service-${self:provider.stage}-logs

But is there a way to get it from a serverless framework with any intrinsic function?

Comment: CloudWatch Logs group associated with a Lambda function generally has this convention:- `/aws/lambda/<function name>`. So may be you can have something like this:- `"LogGroupName": {"Fn::Join": ["", ["/aws/lambda/", {"Ref": "MyLambdaFunction"}]]}`